# Get a string from url after a character

Tags: php

What's the best way to get only the **B005PB3YHU** part from a URL like this
:
[http://www.amazon.com/Designer-Bow-Ties-Y306/dp/B005PB3YHU%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIM6KP3HMBKZXA2EA%26tag%3Dmenbowtie-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB005PB3YHU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005PB3YHU)

Comment: It actually should be B005..., without the preceding 'D', as it's the part of `%3D` symbol.

Comment: Yes you are right on this and I'm sorry for that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @jimp's answers, you need to urldecode first to change the %## to things PHP understands:

```
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/Designer-Bow-Ties-Y306/dp/B005PB3YHU%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIM6KP3HMBKZXA2EA%26tag%3Dmenbowtie-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB005PB3YHU';
# urldecode will remove the %## encoding, and make the url look like:  
# http://www.amazon.com/Designer-Bow-Ties-Y306/dp/B005PB3YHU?SubscriptionId=AKIAIM6KP3HMBKZXA2EA&tag=menbowtie-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B005PB3YHUB005PB3YHU
$query = parse_url(urldecode($url), PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $parts);
echo $parts['creativeASIN'];
```

Comment: True. I assumed the URL in his script would be prepped before this step. Your point is valid. +1

Comment: I was actually just adding the `parse_url` function that wasn't in your original answer, and then realized it didn't work when testing.  Didn't mean to just copy your answer ;)

Comment: @ZakiLaraba - If the answer works for you, click the check to accept an answer

Comment: @ernie I blinked and realized I had left that out. I saved my edits and saw your answer, too. I pointed to your answer about `urldecode` so we wouldn't have identical answers in the end, LOL.

Comment: Thank you both ernie and jimp

Answer (score 4):

Use `parse_url` and `parse_string`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

```
$query = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query,$parts);
echo $parts['creativeASIN'];
```

Comment: @zaki-laraba Check ernie's answer for properly decoding the url, if your script hasn't done that already.